# Find the indefinite integral of $\int \log(\sin(x))\cot(x)\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus

How am I meant to do this? I have tried doing IBP using $u=\log(\sin(x))$ and $v'=\cot(x)$ but it seems to just give you the integral you just did again? Am I meant to do the thing where I set the initial integral to $I$, then use the IBP to get that same integral and subtract it to the other side? But it doesn't seem possible because I get

$$
\int \log(\sin(x))\cot(x)\;\mathrm{d}x=\log(\sin(x))\ln|\sin(x)|-\int \cot(x)\ln|\sin(x)|\;\mathrm{d}x
$$

Where $I_2$ is actually using the natural log and $I_1$ is using log base ten.

Comment: Are you certain that $\log$ is not supposed to be the natural log here?

Comment: $\ln sin x =t$ is a better approach

Comment: substitution: $u=\log(\sin(x))$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich The question is certainly log(x). I do not know anymore than you if I am meant to interpret it otherwise. EDIT: I get it now, the sub of sin(x) lets you remove the cot as well thank you

Comment: In mathematics, $\log$ means the natural log.  But in any case, $\log_e$ and $\log_{10}$ are related by a constant factor, so if you can do this integral with one, you can do it with the other.

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you for your comment. In my highschool, we where always told log just means log base 10 and never log base e. ln was always log base e. I will attempt it now with that in mind.

Comment: @GEdgar I am not sure with that, since $\ln$ seems to be the natural log and $\mathrm{log}$ seems to be the common log. Maybe you mean that $\mathrm{log}$ may refer to the natural log?

Comment: $\log$ can either mean base $e$ or base 10 depending on the source.   Generally engineering texts/higher math texts use base $e$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int \log(\sin x)(\cot x){\rm d}x\\
=\int \log(\sin x)(\frac{ \cos x}{\sin x}){\rm d}x\\
=\int \frac{\log(\sin x)}{\sin x}{\rm d}(\sin x)\\
=\int \log(\sin x){\rm d}(\log(\sin x))\\
=\frac{{\log (\sin x)}^2}{2} +C\\
$$
This is because in calculus $\log x$ is usually assumed to be $\ln x$ unless specified otherwise.

If you assume it to be $\log_{10}x$
Then the above will become
$$\int \log(\sin x)(\cot x){\rm d}x\\
=\int \frac{\ln(\sin x)}{\ln 10}(\cot x){\rm d}x\\
=(\log_{10}e)\int \ln(\sin x)(\frac{ \cos x}{\sin x}){\rm d}x\\
=(\log_{10}e)\int \frac{\ln(\sin x)}{\sin x}{\rm d}(\sin x)\\
=(\log_{10}e)\int \ln(\sin x){\rm d}(\ln(\sin x))\\
=(\log_{10}e)\frac{{\ln (\sin x)}^2}{2} +C\\
$$

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple if you assume the base number of the logarithmic function to be $e$, that is: $\log(\sin(x))=\ln(\sin(x))$

However, if you insist to use the base number of $10$, that is:
$\log(\sin(x))=\lg(\sin(x))$

Then just use a base changing formula for logarithms：
$\log_{10} ^{\sin(x)}=\frac{\ln(\sin(x))}{\ln(10)}$

Noted that the denominator is a constant, also noted that $x$ only takes values in $(0,\infty)$, hence $\ln(\sin(x))=\ln\left|\sin(x)\right|$

Then you can apply the integration by parts as you used previously:

$\frac{1}{2\ln(10)}\ln^{2}{(\sin(x))}+C$, where $C$ is a constant.